# C# Reader Text File, Search for String, Overwrite Line

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader, streamwriter, overwrite

I'm attempting to read a text file if it exists and then search for a specific string at the beginning of each line.  If it exists, I want to overwrite that line with newly input variables.  I'm getting an error when the `Enter/Update Player` button is clicked.  I've noted in the code where the error occurs.

The error I receive:

> "The process cannot access the file  because it is being
>   used by another process. "

I'm assuming this is related to StreamReader/StreamWriter interference, but I can't figure out where the error is coming from.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Namespace1
{
    public partial class FormPokerStats : Form  // FormPokerStats inheriting from class Form
    {
        // declaring and assigning of variables needed for file read/write
        const char DELIM = ',';
        const string FILEPATH = @"C:\C# Project Output\";
        const string FILENAME = "PokerPlayers.txt";

        // declaring instances of Person, Location, and Winnings classes
        Location mycasino = new Location();
        Winnings mywinnings = new Winnings();

        public delegate void Total(double[] total);

        // constructing in/out FileStream/StreamReader/StreamWriter objects
        static FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILEPATH + FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
        static FileStream outFile = new FileStream(FILEPATH + FILENAME, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);

        public FormPokerStats()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // "Enter/Update Player" tab Enter Player button: read/assign user input, write to file, close file stream 
        private void buttonEnterPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Player myplayer = null;

            // if directory does not exist, create it
            if (!(Directory.Exists(FILEPATH)))
            {
                // create directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FILEPATH);
            }

            try
            {
                // read user input and assign to variables; test for empty player inputs and reprompt for input, if necessary
                // Player Information fields
                // if any or all textboxes are left blank
                if ((maskedTextBoxSSN.Text == String.Empty || textBoxFirstName.Text == String.Empty || textBoxLastName.Text == String.Empty
                    || textBoxCasinoName.Text == String.Empty || textBoxCasinoState.Text == String.Empty) ||
                    (maskedTextBoxSSN.Text == String.Empty && textBoxFirstName.Text == String.Empty && textBoxLastName.Text == String.Empty
                    && textBoxCasinoName.Text == String.Empty && textBoxCasinoState.Text == String.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please complete all player information fields.", "Input Error!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // if all textboxes are completed, assign to variables
                    myplayer = new Player(maskedTextBoxSSN.Text, textBoxFirstName.Text, textBoxLastName.Text);
                    mycasino.CasinoName = textBoxCasinoName.Text;
                    mycasino.CasinoState = textBoxCasinoState.Text;
                }

                // read weekly winnings input and assign to appropriate array position; test for empty inputs and assign default value of 0 if empty
                // Week1
                if (textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(0, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(0, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek1Winnings.Text));

                // Week2
                if (textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(1, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(1, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek2Winnings.Text));

                // Week3
                if (textBoxWeek3Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(2, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(2, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek3Winnings.Text));

                // Week4
                if (textBoxWeek4Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(3, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(3, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek4Winnings.Text));

                // Week5
                if (textBoxWeek5Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(4, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(4, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek5Winnings.Text));

                // Week6
                if (textBoxWeek6Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(5, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(5, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek6Winnings.Text));

                // Week7
                if (textBoxWeek7Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(6, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(6, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek7Winnings.Text));

                // Week8
                if (textBoxWeek8Winnings.Text == String.Empty)
                {
                    mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(7, 0);
                }
                else mywinnings.AddNewWinnings(7, Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWeek8Winnings.Text));

                // calculate total winnings by summing WeeklyWinnings array values and assigning to TotalWinnings
                Total pointer = null;
                pointer += new Total(mywinnings.compileTotal);
                pointer(mywinnings.WeeklyWinnings);

                ///////////////////////////////////ERROR HERE////////////////////////////////////

                // check file for input SSN; if exists, overwrite that record and rewrite to file
                if (!(File.Exists(FILEPATH + FILENAME)))
                {
                    List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(FILEPATH + FILENAME));

                    int lineIndex = lines.FindIndex(line => line.StartsWith(myplayer.SocialSecurityNumber));

                    if (lineIndex != -1)
                    {
                        lines[lineIndex] = myplayer.ToString() + mycasino.ToString() + mywinnings.ToString();
                        File.WriteAllLines(FILEPATH + FILENAME, lines);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // writing record to text file
                        writer.WriteLine(myplayer.ToString() + mycasino.ToString() + mywinnings.ToString());
                    }
                }  

                // if record is successfully written, display messagebox
                MessageBox.Show("Wrote " + myplayer.FirstName.ToString() + ' ' + myplayer.LastName.ToString() + " to file with winnings totaling " + mywinnings.TotalWinnings.ToString("C2") + ".", "File Written");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // if format exception is thrown in try, display messagebox with message
                MessageBox.Show("Winnings must be entered at xx.xx (e.g. 34.56).", "Input Error!");
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                // if exception is thrown in try, display messagebox with message
                MessageBox.Show(f.Message, "Error!");
            }

            // clear form textboxes
            ClearTextBoxes();
            maskedTextBoxSSN.Clear();
            writer.Close();
        }

        // "Enter/Update Player" tab Exit button: closes file streams and quits the application
        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // closing file streams
            reader.Close();
            inFile.Close();
            writer.Close();
            outFile.Close();

            // close application
            Application.Exit();
        }

        // "Player List" tab View Player Winnings button: read file records, display records sorted by total winnings descending
        private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clear listbox items
            listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Clear();

            // if file exists
            if (!(File.Exists(FILEPATH + FILENAME)))
            {
                // if file does not exist, display messagebox
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist.", "File Does Not Exist!");
            }
            else
            {
                string[] fields;

                // output header row labels to listbox
                listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Add("First Name\tLast Name\tCasino Name\tCasino State\tTotal Winnings\t");

                // read first record in file
                string recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

                // instantiate an instance of playerList list of tuples
                List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>> playerList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>>();

                // loop through text file records until last record is reached
                while (recordIn != null)
                {
                    // split record into array and assign
                    fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                    Player myplayer = new Player(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);
                    mycasino.CasinoName = fields[3];
                    mycasino.CasinoState = fields[4];
                    mywinnings.TotalWinnings = Convert.ToDouble(fields[13]);

                    // add player to the playerList list of tuples
                    playerList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>(myplayer.FirstName, myplayer.LastName, mycasino.CasinoName, mycasino.CasinoState, mywinnings.TotalWinnings));

                    // read next record in file
                    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                }

                // sort playerList list of tuples by total winnings descending
                playerList.Sort((a, b) => b.Item5.CompareTo(a.Item5));

                // display each record of the playerList list of tuples in the listbox
                foreach (var element in playerList)
                {
                    listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Add(element.Item1 + "\t\t" + element.Item2 + "\t\t" + element.Item3 + "\t\t" + element.Item4 + "\t\t" + element.Item5.ToString("C2"));
                }
            }

            // return file position to 0
            inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        // "Player List" tab Exit button: call buttonExit_Click method
        private void buttonExit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call buttonExit_Click method
            buttonExit_Click(sender, e);
        }

        // method to clear listbox items when "Player List" tab is left
        private void tabPagePlayerList_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clear listbox items
            listBoxOutputRecords.Items.Clear();
        }

        // method to clear textbox controls
        private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).Clear();
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(Controls);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it because you are reading and writing the same file? Try to use temp file first to write on.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're closing all the streams on existing the application. You need to close the streams as soon as you have used them. For example, once you have read the file contents to reader, you can close file stream. Similarly, when you have moved the reader stream to writer stream, you need to close the reader stream right away.

Your above error is surely occurring due to some open stream. So to make sure file is not somehow being accessed by another process, just close your streams as soon as they're used. Try this and if further help required, do share.